# Modificaciones en tabla

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.9
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: localhost:3306
-- Tiempo de generación: 20-07-2018 a las 10:11:28
-- Versión del servidor: 10.2.16-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.1.17

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `u743999068_mm`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `citas`
--

CREATE TABLE `citas` (
  `id_cita` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `nombre_cita` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ok` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `horarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `horarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `horas` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Cliente` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `dia` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anyo` int(4) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--


--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `Noticias`
--

CREATE TABLE `Noticias` (
  `id_noticias` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_noticia` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `page_heading` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `secondary_text` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `post_title` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `text2` varchar(6000) NOT NULL,
  `text3` varchar(4000) NOT NULL,
  `text4` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `user_pub` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `foto1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `foto2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `foto3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `foto4` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `Proyectos`
--

CREATE TABLE `Proyectos` (
  `id_proyecto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `texto1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `texto2` varchar(2000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `Usuarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `Usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `kind` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




--
-- Indices de la tabla `citas`
--
ALTER TABLE `citas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_cita`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `horarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `horarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `Noticias`
--
ALTER TABLE `Noticias`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_noticias`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `Proyectos`
--
ALTER TABLE `Proyectos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_proyecto`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `Usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `Usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `horarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `horarios`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=122;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `Noticias`
--
ALTER TABLE `Noticias`
  MODIFY `id_noticias` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `Proyectos`
--
ALTER TABLE `Proyectos`
  MODIFY `id_proyecto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `Usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `Usuarios`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=16;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `citas`
--
ALTER TABLE `citas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `id_cita` FOREIGN KEY (`id_cita`) REFERENCES `horarios` (`id`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Me gustaria ver si se puede mejorar esta base de datos, y añadir una relación entre la tabla horarios y usuarios por medio de una tabla intermedia llamada citas.

Cuando un usuario se registra, se almacenan los datos en la tabla Usuarios.
Una vez que loguea, puede pedir citas.
Se muestra un horario y selecciona una fecha, la cual se guarda en la tabla horarios. Y se guarda el campo id y Cliente de la tabla horarios en la tabla citas como id_cita y nombre_cita respectivamente.

Si el usuario no cancela la cita, y llega el dia de la cita, asi mantengo una tabla que guarda al usuario, que ya puedo llamar Cliente ya que ha acudido a la cita.
No se si se entiende mejor el planteamiento.
Considero la tabla citas como una tabla intermedia entre usuarios y horarios.
Las demás tablas no tienen relacion con ninguna, ya que son cosas independientes.

Comment: No se entiende bien tu pregunta, ni tampoco tu diseño. Por ejemplo, la tabla `horarios` ¿por qué no pones un `id_cliente` (porque supongo que tienes o deberías tener una tabla `Clientes`)? ¿Por qué no aprovechas de que una columna `DATETIME` te permite guardar **dia, mes, año y hora** y sustituyes las 4 columnas dedicadas para esos datos por una sola columna `DATETIME`? En cuanto a las relaciones no te digo nada porque no explicas nada de lo que hace o para que se utilizará tu modelo de datos.

Comment: Buenas, la tabla citas es donde quiero guardar los usuarios que acuden a una cita (y ya son "Clientes").
Dispongo de una tabla horarios donde los usuarios pueden elegir una hora para acudir.
Dispongo de la tabla Usuarios, ya que para poder pedir una cita deben registrarse previamente.
Por ello, lo que quiero conseguir que en la tabla Citas solamente hayan valores válidos, como los nombres de los usuarios (de la tabla Usuarios) y id´s válidos (de la tabla Horarios).

La tabla citas podria ser llamada perfectamente "Clientes", porque ese es su cometido.

Comment: Todo lo que dices en tu anterior comentario debería ser parte de la pregunta y aclarar todo lo que hace tu diseño si quieres que te ayudemos. Leyéndote veo que hay varios errores ya en el planteamiento (en cómo imaginas el diseño en tu cabeza).

Comment: @A.Cedano, acabo de editar la pregunta, intentando explicar mejor lo que pretendo.
Gracias

Comment: Ahora se entiende mejor. De entrada, en la tabla `horarios` en lugar del nombre del cliente debería ir el `id` (de la tabla `Usuarios`). Por otra parte,  todavía faltan algunas puntualizaciones. Voy a seguir comentando cosas para que entiendas la complejidad del problema: ¿el fin de la tabla `horarios` cuál es en sí, manejar de forma controlada un rango de horas en las que se pueden pedir citas? ¿cómo piensas controlar los festivos o no laborables de modo que nadie pueda pedir citas en esos días? ¿Cómo piensas bloquear los rangos de citas ya reservadas en un día y hora dados?

Comment: Utilizo un calendario datepicker en los cuales he bloqueado los findes de semana y los dias anteriores al dia actual. Los dias "festivos" por ahora no los contemplo. Es para un aprendizaje básico.
Un usuario unicamente puede tener activa una única cita. Hasta que no se cancele esa o se lleve a cabo, no puede pedir otra.
Para que otro usuario pueda pedir una cita, hago un select donde "Cliente==''". Asi solo muestro los horarios en los que no hay asignado ningun nombre.

Comment: Porque hay una necesidad de agregar relaciones de negocios en la db, cuando eso debe estar controlado por el sistema de ingreso??? la base de datos da esas facilidades, pero no deberia preocuparte eso, si no entender como tienen que funcionar tus relaciones con respecto a tus datos.

Comment: Si, está controlado, pero queria crear una base más correcta, ya que el proyecto que estoy realizando es de aprendizaje de un curso que ando realizando.
Todo es por aprender y mejorar lo posible.